# Can't get row by id from array in localstorage

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have an array of items in my localstorage like this :

```
[ {id: 1, name: "test1"}, {id: 2, name: "test2"}, {id: 3, name: "test3"}]
```

When I try to select a row by name in my array everthing goes well but if I use the id the logs return
"Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

**TS**

```
getContacts() {
    var storedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
    console.log(storedContacts );
    this.tabContacts = storedContacts ;
   }


 getContact(id) {
        //returns -1 when I use the id
        var i = this.tabContacts
          .map(function (x) {
            return x.id;
          })
          .indexOf(id);
      
        this.tabContacts.find((x) => x.id == this.tabContacts[i].id);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
           <tr
            *ngFor="let contact of tabContacts"
            (click)="getContact(contact.id)"
            id="tr-{{ contact.id }}"
          >
            <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Could you show me how you get the localstorage data?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem lie here  :

```
   <tr
      (click)="getContact(contact.name)"
            ...
```

you're passing name when someone clicks on `<tr>` and filtering on `id` from the array.

You should do  like :

html :

```
   <tr
    *ngFor="let contact of tabContacts"
    (click)="getContact(contact.name)"
    id="tr-{{ contact.id }}"
  >
    <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
  </tr>
```

TS :

```
  getContact(key) {
  
        var i = this.tabContacts
          .map(function (x) {
            // change this based on the field you pass from html 
            return x.id; // or x.name
          })
          .indexOf(key);
      
        .... rest of the code            
  }
```

P.S :  your logic is not that good.